# Azure DevOps Set Build number variable in a Build Task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

In Azure DevOps, I created a Build. In that Build I created a ProjectBuildNumber Pipeline variable that is Settable at queue time. That variable is then used under Options -> Build number format to set my build number displayed in Azure.

However, I am trying to make that ProjectBuildNumber variable settable in the code I am building/deploying. Is there a way I can have a Task in my Build to update that ProjectBuildNumber and update the Build number in Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a way I can have a Task in my Build to update that ProjectBuildNumber and update the Build number in Azure DevOps?

The answer is **yes**.

You could add a `Inline Power-Shell` task in your build definition to update the value of `ProjectBuildNumber` and then update the build number base on the it:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ProjectBuildNumber;]YourUpdateValue"

Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]xxx.$(ProjectBuildNumber).xxx.xxx"
```

Check the [Logging Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) during the build for some more details:

[image]

**Besides**, if you want to update the value of a Pipeline Variable on the **UI/web portal**, you need the REST API ([Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#request-body)) to update the value of the build pipeline definition variable from a build task.

There is a very similar thread, you can check the answer for the details:

[How to modify Azure DevOps release definition variable from a release task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042605/how-to-modify-azure-devops-release-definition-variable-from-a-release-task/53060141#53060141)

Note:Change the API to the build definitions:

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.0
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works!! Thnx

Answer (score 1):

We can update Build Number in Azure Devops via two ways .
One from Option Section/Tab and 2nd Via PowerShell Scripts.

To update the build number from Power shell Script.. We need to add following script..

Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(VersionNumber).$(VersionRevision)"

Here we have used 2 variables : VersionNumber  and VersionRevision.
We need to add 2 variables in PipeLine Configurations..
VersionNumber will be the desired number and VersionRevision is the counter number that will be updated every time, when ever we will create a new build.
Please check the complete demonstration from You tube video

https://youtu.be/WBmFTmzopiQ

Answer (score 1):

Have created power shell task for that

```
# replace existing Build.BuildNumber with
# NAME_2.1.2.54_20211220.16_345
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Update Version Number'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: | 
      $lines = Get-ChildItem ".\Project\My Project\AssemblyInfo.vb" 
      $match = $lines | Select-String -Pattern "\<Assembly\:\s+AssemblyVersion\(""(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)""\)\>"
      $version = $match.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
      [Version]::Parse($version) # validate
      $tag = "NAME_$($version)_$(Build.BuildNumber)_$(Build.BuildId)"
      Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$tag"
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out the Microsoft documentation on this: [Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-pipeline)

Depending on your operating system you can add a Powershell/Batch/Bash Task and change the variable.

Edit: After some research it appears that the change of the variable will show up in the **following task**. Take a look at this issue [Update environment variables using `task.setvariable` in a bash script does not work](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/2018)

Comment: I have tried that, but that does not seem to set a Pipeline Variable.