# AWS CodeBuild set Build Number

Tags: amazon-web-services, versioning, aws-codebuild

Is it possible to override AWS CodeBuild's Build Number to support a custom numbering scheme, say Semantic Versioning?

[image]

I know it can be done in Azure DevOps ([Azure DevOps Set Build number variable in a Build Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58286114/azure-devops-set-build-number-variable-in-a-build-task))

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ProjectBuildNumber;]YourUpdateValue"

Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]xxx.$(ProjectBuildNumber).xxx.xxx"
```

**Is it possible in AWS CodeBuild?**

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-buildspec-artifact-naming.html see this once

Comment: @aviboy2006 - thx for the link; but that's for naming **Artifacts**.  I want to name the **Build**.  Unless I'm missing something, I didn't see a way to update the Build here.  This just controls file names that are saved in s3 buckets.