# Automatically display version of code in angular app deployed by Azure

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, azure-devops

Currently we are having issues knowing what version of code is in what environment and Azure hasn't always been incredibly consistent in always deploying the latest files.

Also, It is difficult for our testers to know what version of code is deployed.

```
There really is no code to show
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using appservice?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Azure pipelines to build and deploy your app, this [blog](https://medium.com/ngconf/angular-on-azure-part-i-d842e8f76462) provides detailed guidance.

In addition, if you use build number to display this version of code, you could [configure run or build numbers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic). Also you could create build number variable(for example `ProjectBuildNumber`) and make it settable in the code when building/deploying.

You could add an `Inline Power-Shell task` in your build definition to update the value of `ProjectBuildNumber` and then update the build number base on the it:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ProjectBuildNumber;]YourUpdateValue"

Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]xxx.$(ProjectBuildNumber).xxx.xxx"
```

See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58286114/azure-devops-set-build-number-variable-in-a-build-task) for more details.

BTW, you could use [DevOps Starter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/overview) service to build and deploy your app. See this tutorial: [Set up a CI/CD pipeline for a Java app with Azure DevOps Starter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-java?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fdevops-project%2Ftoc.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) for quickstart.