# Azure DevOps Cancel deployment of stage when deploying another stage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, release-management

We currently have our Azure DevOps release setup in the following way:

[image: Release Setup]

What I'm trying to accomplish is to cancel the 2:00 PM deployment if the 9:00 AM deployment triggers, as well as cancel the 9:00 AM deployment if the 2:00 PM deployment triggers since we don't really want to deploy the same code twice, or even deploy the previous day's code the following day.

Does anyone know if a way to do this in Azure DevOps?

I've done a lot of searching for extensions, etc. to see if I can find anything, but so far have not been successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why you'd have two stages for this. Have a single stage and two scheduled times.

Comment: You can't have 2 scheduled times unfortunately :-(

Comment: You schedule the release, not the stage.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, you may try to use Release Gates with Rest Api or Azure Functions. You can find example here: [Azure DevOps release gates with Azure Functions, PowerShell and VS Code](https://medium.com/@shayki5/azure-devops-release-gates-with-azure-functions-powershell-and-vs-code-cd98a920887f)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you trigger the release at 9:00 AM. Then you can take the following steps to implement it:

1.Add a variable named flag and set it as true in the Variable Tab

[image]

2.Add a PowerShell Task to your Test Stage, Starting 9:00 AM Stage and Starting 2:00 PM Stage

(1) Add a powershell task at the end of your Test Stage to set the flag to true.

(2) Add a powershell task on the top of Starting 9:00 AM Stage  to check if the variable flag is true, If flag is false then fail this task,  Below script is for example.

$flag = “$(flag)”

if(-Not $flag)

{

```
exit 1
```

}

Add a powershell task at the end of Starting 9:00 AM Stage  to set the flag to false, if this stage is deployed successfully.

Repeat above steps for 2:00 PM Stage.

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042605/how-to-modify-azure-devops-release-definition-variable-from-a-release-task

Comment: @MrCyber Is the plan given by me or Shamrai Aleksander helpful to you? If you have any questions, feel free to tell us.