# Is there an env var for the build source branch of a build triggered by another build?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a build triggered by another build.
I would like to get SourceBranchName of the build triggered the current build.
[Azure predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) offers only the following variables about the "triggered by" build:

1. Build.TriggeredBy.BuildId
2. Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionId
3. Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionName
4. Build.TriggeredBy.BuildNumber
5. Build.TriggeredBy.ProjectID

And when I tried to access $(Build.TriggeredBy.SourceBranchName) I got empty string..

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you trigger the build, with build . trigger or with rest api?

Comment: On the triggers tab in the azure pipeline's web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an env var for the build source branch of a build triggered by another build?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

Just as you can see, MS provide does not provide the predefined variables about `Build.TriggeredBy.SourceBranchName`, so there is no such out of box env var to get the build source branch of a build triggered.

You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps:

[image]

**As workaround**, we could invoke REST API ([Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/release/definitions/update?view=vsts-rest-4.1)) to update the value of the triggered build definition variable in invoking pipeline task:

```
PUT https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=5.0
```

We could transfer the `Build.SourceBranchName` by REST API to the triggered build pipeline as a veriable, so that we could access it in the triggered build pipeline.

You could check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042605/how-to-modify-azure-devops-release-definition-variable-from-a-release-task/53060141#53060141) for some more details.

Hope this helps.