# How to delete variable in azure devops release through powershell

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I have azure DevOps release and I would like to delete release variables post one stage of deployment. could you please provide some pointers on how to do this? I know how to update the value of the variable using API but am unable to delete the variable. Any pointers are highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete the release pipeline variable during the release process, you could use the  [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/Definitions/Update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=vsts-rest-4.1) Rest API.

Here is the PowerShell example:

```
$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/Release/definitions/$($env:RELEASE_DEFINITIONID)?api-version=5.0-preview.3"
Write-Host "URL: $url"
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}


$pipeline.variables.PSObject.Properties.Remove('variablename')

####****************** update the modified object **************************
$json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99


$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

write-host "==========================================================" 
Write-host "The value of Varialbe 'test' is deleted"
write-host "=========================================================="
```

The  following code is used to delete the variable.

```
$pipeline.variables.PSObject.Properties.Remove('variablename')
```

For more detailed info, you could refer to this ticket: [How to modify Azure DevOps release definition variable from a release task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042605/how-to-modify-azure-devops-release-definition-variable-from-a-release-task)