# Azure DevOps Pipeline - use same variable with distinct content for distinct task in same stage

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, pipeline

I am creating a new pipeline for deploy multiple apps in azure devops, for sample:

[image]

I wanna make xml variable substitution for sample ConnectionString in web.config.

For sample:

[image]

But variables only can group by scope Stage and not by task in same stage, can I do this somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It is not supported to definite variables with the same name in same stage but different tasks. The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#custom-variables) has mentioned the scopes of variables.

> Custom variables can be defined at various scopes.
>
> Share values across **all of the definitions in a project** by using
> **variable groups**. Choose a variable group when you need to use the same
> values across all the definitions, stages, and tasks in a project, and
> you want to be able to change the values in a single place. You define
> and manage variable groups in the Library tab.
>
> Share values across **all of the stages** by using **release pipeline
> variables**. Choose a release pipeline variable when you need to use the
> same value across all the stages and tasks in the release pipeline,
> and you want to be able to change the value in a single place. You
> define and manage these variables in the Variables tab in a release
> pipeline. In the Pipeline Variables page, open the Scope drop-down
> list and select "Release". By default, when you add a variable, it is
> set to Release scope.
>
> Share values across **all of the tasks within one specific stage** by
> using **stage variables**. Use a stage-level variable for values that vary
> from stage to stage (and are the same for all the tasks in an stage).
> You define and manage these variables in the Variables tab of a
> release pipeline. In the Pipeline Variables page, open the Scope
> drop-down list and select the required stage. When you add a variable,
> set the Scope to the appropriate environment.

This maybe a workaroud to change the value of variable after one task.

[image]

Please refer to this issue: [How to modify Azure DevOps release definition variable from a release task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042605/how-to-modify-azure-devops-release-definition-variable-from-a-release-task)