# how to increment and save variable in azure devops pipeline

Tags: variables, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Anyone know how can I increment the value of a variable under some conditions, (for example only if the pipeline succeeded) and save it for next build?

Example:
I set a variable: number=5.
If the pipeline succeeded and job number 2 ran, I want number=6 on the next build.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish by doing this.

Comment: Increment version - I need to increase the last digit of the version, but only if the pipeline succeeded, so cannot use counter.

Comment: Why not use something like GitVersion to manage generating valid semver automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value of your variable by using following command:

Bash

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=number;]newValue"
```

PowerShell

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=number;]newValue"
```

Basically, your number will be set to the `newValue` after running this command.

Comment: Will this save the value of the variable for the next build?

Comment: It does not work for me, the value is simply reset to 5 with the variable declaration in the next run. You probably need to work with git or a text file to increase the version number

Answer (score -1):

> how to increment and save variable in azure devops pipeline

Since you could not use the counter, you could try to use the REST API [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) to update the variable:

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=5.0
```

The test scripts:

```
$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/definitions/{definitionId}?api-version=6.0"

Write-Host "URL: $url"
$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"

$counter = [int]$pipeline.variables.Test.value

$counter++

$pipeline.variables.Test.value = $counter

####****************** update the modified object **************************
$json = @($pipeline) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99


$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}

write-host "==========================================================" 
Write-host "The value of Varialbe 'Test' is updated to" $updatedef.variables.Test.value
```

**Note:** We neeed to declare the variable type as `int` before we can use `++`

```
$counter = [int]$pipeline.variables.Test.value

$counter++
```

If you met any premission issue, please refer [this thead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042605/how-to-modify-azure-devops-release-definition-variable-from-a-release-task/53060141#53060141) for some more details.